# Go + App Engine Datastore: How to filter out rows that are null?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

How do I filter out rows that are null? I know it's hard to find only-null rows, but hopefully this should be easier.

I'd like to do the following:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("MY_KIND").Filter("MY_ID !=", nil)
```

... but Filter doesn't support the != comparator. FYI, using this GQL syntax in the Datastore Viewer works just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_KIND WHERE MY_ID != NULL
```

Comment: did you force the result as null or you mean when the attribute is not filled?  the datastore doesn't consider "null" to equal "nothing in the attribute".   If you mean "nothing in the attribute", just order by that attribute, and the datastore, by design, won't return rows with "nothing in the attribute".  You might need to change your model (take out a default = null or something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `greater` filter with the appropriate value (> 0 for numbers, > "" for strings).

Typically an ID cannot be an empty string or zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me.

```
// Datastore entity with null value
// `DeletedAt` in my case is *time.Time
{
  "DeletedAt": NULL,
  "Version": 1,
  ...
}
```

Here's my query to get records where `DeletedAt` is `NULL`:

```
datastore.NewQuery("MyKind").Filter("DeletedAt =", (*time.Time)(nil))
```

Hope that this will be helpful to someone of you.